# How to parse the next json

Tags: json

I have the following JSON text that I need to parse to get pageName, pagePic, post_id, etc.

What is the required code?

```
    {
   "pageInfo": {
         "pageName": "abc",
         "pagePic": "http://example.com/content.jpg"
    }
    "posts": [
         {
              "post_id": "123456789012_123456789012",
              "actor_id": "1234567890",
              "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/photo.jpg",
              "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
              "message": "Sounds cool. Can't wait to see it!",
              "likesCount": "2",
              "comments": [],
              "timeOfPost": "1234567890"
         }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You need to go elsewhere

Comment: `JSON.parse('my string');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonString = "pageInfo": { "pageName": "abc", "pagePic": "http://example.com/content.jpg" } "posts": [ { "post_id": "123456789012_123456789012", "actor_id": "1234567890", "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/photo.jpg", "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe", "message": "Sounds cool. Can't wait to see it!", "likesCount": "2", "comments": [], "timeOfPost": "1234567890" } ] }
JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

here is the code

Comment: Such questions should not be answered. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. "Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which make no attempt to find an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer